# Adding users to a public api without restricting the client

Tags: rest, web-services, authentication, api-design

I am writing a public rest api, that uses api tokens that are one per application that uses it. I want to give the ability for the client to create users of the application, but not restrict them with what a user should be.

So I have API_USERS that need a token to authenticate to do any requests to the api. Lets say its an api for messages. So the messages from one application will be identified by that token, but how can I let the application that is using the api to be able to create their own users so that the messages in the database, are first uniquely identified for the application and then uniquely identified for the different users of the application if the application has such needs.

My idea is that I can just add another field like MESSAGE_OWNER and let the user handle how to create unique token for his users and maybe use his own database for storing users. Would that be a good solution? Is there another way I am not seeing?

Comment: I am not sure if it's exactly what you want, but have a look the Spotify API for inspiration as it has a flow similar to the one you described - https://developer.spotify.com

Comment: It looks interesting, but it's not what I want. The api defines users and you can access them thru tokens. I want to have the option for users, but not define what one looks like